# Работа с бинарным файлом/запись структуры в бинарный файл - C++

Tags: c++, структуры

Нужна помощь в записи структуры в бинарный файл. Не могу записать и считать структуру с файла, так же нужно организовать:

```
Добaвление в структуру
Удаление из структуры
Поиск по фамилии
Подсчет среднего бала за выбранным номером группы
```

Сама структура состоит из:

Имени студента
Фамилии студента
Группы
Среднего бала

Желательно это всё на форме сделать, но если кто-то знает как сделать все это хотя бы в консоле, подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете записать структуру в файл, заранее определив оператор ввода или записав каждое поле, открывая файл в режиме бинарной  записи.
Но читать сможете, только если заранее вам известно количество символов, записанных в файле как поля структуры. 
  Если поможет понять, то по вашей просьбе продемонстрирую пример, как  выводить на консоль строку в бинарном виде и как читать  бинарные записи:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{    
    string s = "abcdefgh", res;
    bitset<8> b;
    size_t n = s.size();
    // записываем строку посимвольно в бинарном виде
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        b = s[i];
        cout << b << endl;
    }

    // если вводить все что получили на выводе, то  res будет иметь значение s
    while( cin >> b)
        res += char(b.to_ulong());
    cout << res; 
    return 0;
}
```

если в чем то ошибся, надеюсь найдутся те, кто любезно поравят

Comment: Вывод в виде битов имеет довольно далёкое отношение к работе с файлами в бинарном режиме.

Comment: @insolor,  это понятно, только я  выполнил просьбу автора: " но если кто-то знает как сделать все это хотя бы в консоле"

Comment: Имелся в виду пользовательский интерфейс - "это всё на форме сделать, но если кто-то знает как сделать все это хотя бы в консоле" - т.е. в GUI или CUI.